# Can VB.net take control of a VBA form?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro containing a form. I would like for VB.net to either hide the form or take control of it and click the "X" button or the custom "Exit" button.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: You'll need SendKeys, or something similar.  http://visualstudiovb.net/send-text-to-another-applications-window-using-sendkeys/

Answer (score 2):

Sendkeys are highly unreliable.

If you can automate the Excel from VB.Net the I would recommend that. If you are interested in automating Excel from VB.Net then see [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/).

If you don't want to automate but want to directly handle it then I would recommend using the `FindWindow` and `Sendmessage` API to get control of the form. See this Example.

Let's say that there is a userform in Excel which looks like this

[image]

Use this code form VB.Net

**CODE**:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow( _
         ByVal lpClassName As String, _
         ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
        ByVal Msg As UInteger, _
        ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Ret As Integer

        '~~> Get the handle of the Excel Userform named "Example"
        Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Example")

        '~~> If Found
        If Ret <> 0 Then
            '~~> Close the Window
            SendMessage(Ret, WM_CLOSE, CLng(0), CLng(0))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Siddharth, I ran into a problem...my code is opening the workbook with the VBA userform. The userform is taking control so the findwindow line seems to be useless because I'm manually closing the form. Any way to combine the open command and the findwindow command?

Comment: If you are manually closing the form then how will findwindow find it :)?

Comment: The code halts until I manually close the form, so you are right, the findwindow isn't useless. I have a dictionary that holds file path, excel application pairs so I can open multiple files in different instances without hard coding the excel objects. so the line I'm using is....Item.Value.Workbooks.Open(Item.Key)-this opens the file fine. The code doesn't advance to the FindWindow line until I manually close the VBA form.

Comment: In your VBA, open the form in modeless mode... `Userform1.Show vbModeless` NOw try it

Comment: Well, I just realized I actually want to do the exact opposite. I want the VBA form to show. Is there a way to tell .net to open the workbook without focus so that the form doesn't halt code? I've tried "application.enableevents=false", then run the "Workbook_open" VBA macro, but got no luck so far. Thank you so much for your help Siddharth!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `Userform1.Show vbModeless` will ensure that your code will not halt...

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try and get with you later.

Comment: That works. I do have one last lazy request though! I have 20 workbooks that this code will open, so rather than having to modify each workbook, is there a way for the .net code to tell the userform to be modeless?

Comment: Hmmm Somehow I missed your comment. I see that you have also unmarked this post as an answer. Did my post not answer your original question?

Comment: So I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and don't understand yet all the rules. The vbModeless reply fit my answer more than your answer reply, but I don't think I can mark a reply as an answer. If you can tell me how, I will be more than glad to help you out and mark something as answered!

Comment: What is your question? The above code does what you wanted in the original question...

Comment: You answered with the "FindWindow" option. I was saying your "vbModeless" comment answered my question (the one I voted as helpful), but I can't select it as the answer. Is there a way to do it?